# Magento: Using one quantity field for all products options?

Tags: php, magento, product

I'm trying to create a Bundled product in Magento with multiple options.

Each simple product I have is tiered in price.

Example;

> Thank You Card Bundled Product ($0)
>
> Dropdown Option 1: Colored Envelopes ($0.90-$0.50 Depending on
>   Quantity, color in dropdown)
>
> Dropdown Option 2: Size of Card ($3-$2 Depending on Size chosen and
>   quantity)
>
> Quantity = 0-100

But when you have multiple product options each one has a quantity field they need to fill out, I'd like to just have one field that would represent all the options so the customer doesn't have to fill out multiple boxes and we don't have a problem with people entering different numbers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: try using hidden fields and jQuery for this purpose...

Comment: @SKV I think that is what I'll have to do. jQuery isn't my strong suit but I'll figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set the "User Defined Qty" to no on each of the associated products then these qty fields are useless anyway.

All you need to do in your current theme is apply a CSS rule to hide these fields. If you are using the default theme then you could apply -

```
.qty-holder { display: none; }
```

qty-holder is the class of the span the holds the label and input field for qty of each option.

The bundle itself still has a qty field to buy multiples of the same configuration however its field and qty have a separate class so won't be affected by this rule.

Comment: Was my first thought. But since each option had tiered pricing depending on what the quantity is so when you select no to the "User defined" option it always treats it as 1, doesn't care how many you put in the main bundle products quantity. That's my problem.